# Discrete Math - Propositional Equivalence

Tags: equivalence-relations

Show that this propositional equivalence is true:

¬( ↔ ) ≡ (¬ ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ¬)

My try out was to compare by truth table, but it is not that the exercice is asking. I need the resolution using arguments as "the morgan" and other simplifications as "(p-->q) ≡ ~p V q."

When I tryed the simplification on the right side, I could reach something like that:

Changing the sides to be easier...

(~R ^ S) V (R ^ ~S) ≡ ~(R <-> S)

~[(~R ^ S) V (R ^ ~S)] ≡ (R V S)

~[(~R ^ S) V ~(R -> S)] ≡ (R V S)

(R V ~S) ^ ~(R -> S) ≡ (R V S)

Matching those two sides, in truth table, it doesn't get the same result. The left side gets the result: F V F F; and the right side results in F V V F. Proving that my resolution is wrong. Can someone help me with this argumentation?
Thanks!

Comment: Well, don't keep us waiting, what happens when you try those simplifications? What have you tried? You seen to know how to proceed.

Comment: Should be noted that it's not "the Morgan", its "DeMorgan's law(s)". Named after Augustus DeMorgan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is way easier to reformulate and develop the left hand side.

First, we need to reformulate this $\leftrightarrow$ :
$$r \leftrightarrow s \equiv (r \to s) \wedge (s\to r) \equiv (\neg r \vee s) \wedge (\neg s \vee r) $$

Now, you just "push" the negation inside using de morgan's laws :

$$\begin{array}{l} {} \neg (r \leftrightarrow s) \\
\equiv  \neg \big( (\neg r \vee s) \wedge (\neg s \vee r) \big) \\
\equiv \big(\neg (\neg r \vee s)\big) \vee \big(\neg (\neg s \vee r)\big) \\
\equiv (r \wedge \neg s) \vee (s \wedge \neg r)
 \end{array}$$